# What is this error in XAMPP starting? How can i fix this?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, xampp

> rash@rash's lap:~$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start

```
sudo: unable to resolve host rash's lap
[sudo] password for rash: 
Starting XAMPP for Linux 5.6.3-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
XAMPP:  Starting diagnose... 
XAMPP:  Sorry, I've no idea what's going wrong. 
XAMPP:  Please contact our forum http://www.apachefriends.org/f/
```

> Last 10 lines of "/opt/lampp/logs/error_log":

```
tail: cannot open ‘/opt/lampp/logs/error.log’ for reading: No such file or directory
XAMPP: Starting MySQL.../opt/lampp/share/xampp/xampplib: line 39: test: /opt/lampp/var/mysql/rash's: binary operator expected
ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...fail.
Contents of "/opt/lampp/var/proftpd/start.err":
rash_s_lap proftpd[5128]: warning: unable to determine IP address of 'rash_s_lap'
rash_s_lap proftpd[5128]: error: no valid servers configured
rash_s_lap proftpd[5128]: Fatal: error processing configuration file '/opt/lampp/etc/proftpd.conf'
```

rash@rash's lap:~$

Comment: Check if you have /etc/hosts with the correct ip and hostname

Comment: it not works. i tried it

Comment: [Duplicate question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/583024/what-is-this-error-in-xampp-starting-how-can-i-fix-this). Choose one site where to get a response either Stackoverflow or askubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all previous versions of lamp and all of its components (apache, php, mysql, smtp ...) and reinstall it one by one.

Installing apache, php and mysql for ubuntu 14.04.

Step 1:

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install apache2 mysql-client mysql-server php5

You could be asked for password.

Step 2:

> sudo apt-get install php5-curl php5-gd php5-intl php5-mysql
>
> sudo service apache2 restart

Step 3:

> Open http://127.0.0.1

Now you have a working apache server with php and mysql.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem on the Ubuntu operating system. Then I realized that it was because I changed `listen` in `httpd.conf` to (my ip address:80) and my IP got changed.  That was the problem.  So open `/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf` and check if `listen` is set to `80` or something else.  If it's not `80` set it to `80`. Restart your apache server. Then you should be all set.

Answer (score 1):

In my case i use this first

```
sudo apt-get install net-tools
```

If apache server fail issue then

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 stop

/opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

I think it will work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

> user3686982 gave a nice answer. Installing the individual softwares that constitute xampp is a good thing and I think it is preferable.

If you still want to go with the xampp installer, Uninstall  all xampp versions and download the xampp installer from here at [apachefriends](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html). This link will show you [how to use the installer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9P0rjonfPo)

> Also Apache is not working because another server is already running at that port 80. You can either stop apache2 
>    `sudo service apache2 stop`
>   or change the port of your [Xampp apache server](http://complete-concrete-concise.com/web-tools/how-to-change-the-apache-port-in-xampp).